# Grab specific data from VNClassificationObservation

Tags: swift, coreml

I am using inceptionV3.model for an app that predicts images . I want to grab the image classification name and the percentage probablilty from VNClassificationObservation.

29206794-409A-498E-800F-8432610821B0, revision 1, 0.805825 "cheetah, chetah, Acinonyx jubatus",

I need to get percentage 0.805825  and the name "Cheetah , Chetah , Acinonyx jubatus". But i am not sure how i will go on that

Answer (score 0):

`VNClassificationObservation` has `identifier` and `confidence` properties that will give you these things.